# Bold Text conditionally in JSX

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am working on a Next.JS Google Clone.

I am trying to write some CSS to bold the search input in the search results objects from using the Google API.

How can I conditonally bold the {router.query.term} in my {result.snippet} if the search term is present in that value?

Header.js

```
function Header() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchInputRef = useRef(null);

  const search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const term = searchInputRef.current.value;

    if (!term) return;

    router.push(`/search?term=${term}`);
  };
  return (
    <header>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={searchInputRef}
            className="flex-grow w-full focus:outline-none"
            defaultValue={router.query.term}
          />
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

SearchResults.js

```
function SearchResults({ results }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {results.items?.map((result) => (
        <div key={result.link}>
          <p className="line-clamp-2">{result.snippet}</p>
        </div>
      ))}

      <PaginationButtons />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: What does `result.snippet` look like? Could you make an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with inline styles;

```
<p className="line-clamp-2"  
style={{fontWeight: condition ? bold : normal}}
>
{result.snippet}
</p>
```